# How to use linux command line ftp with a @ sign in my username?

Tags: linux, ftp

How can I run this on linux command line when my username has an `@` sign in the middle?

```
ftp -u user:password@host/destination_folder/ sourcefile.txt
```

My username is `info@domain.com` and it thinks my host is `domain.com`.

NOTE: This is an unattended upload, so I can't just type in the username and password.

Comment: I'm trying both. Thanks guys!!

Comment: This seems like it belongs on http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As an alternative, if you don't want to create config files (or you don't want to rely on the behavior of the system-specific *ftp* command), do the unattended upload with `curl` instead of `ftp`:

```
curl -u user:password -T file ftp://server/dir/file
```

If you don't want `ps` (process list) to show the password passed to *curl* for security reasons, see [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794842/forcing-curl-to-get-a-password-from-the-environment).

Comment: -1 not because it is wrong, but it does not help him with his problem - just gives an alternative. If it is not impossible to do what he wants with what he wants, why should he change the tool?

Comment: @OliverFriedrich: One possible reason to change the tool is right in the first paragraph in the answer: *if you don't want to create config files*. Creating and maintaining config files is a mental burden, and it can also be a key storage security issue, because then a password is saved to disk. Another possible reason to change the tool is that the arguments of the *ftp* command vary from system to system, and *curl* is more portable.

Comment: @OliverFriedrich: The problem of the OP is not obvious from the question (it may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)): maybe they want to use the *ftp* command, maybe they want to do unattended uploads to an FTP server, using any tool. My answer fits the latter, other answers fit the former.

Answer (score 26):

Try this: use "%40" in place of the "@"

Comment: Doesn't work for me unfortunately :( Host treats %40 as individual characters, not @

Answer (score 12):

Try to define the account in a `~/.netrc` file like this:

```
machine host login info@domain.com password mypassword
```

Check [`man netrc`](http://man.cx/netrc) for details.

Comment: Both answers are right, but I gave it to pts because his was easier.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 6):

I simply type `ftp hostdomain.com` and the very next prompt asked me to enter a name, if it wasn't the same as my current user.

I guess it depends on how your FTP is configured. That is, whether it assumes the same username (if not provided) or asks. the good news is that even without a solution, next time you face this it might Just Work™ for you :D

Answer (score 2):

A more complete answer would be it is not possible with ftp(at least the ftp program installed on centos 6).

Since you wanted an un-attended process, "pts"'s answer will work fine.

> Do the unattended upload with curl instead of ftp:

```
curl -u user:password -T file ftp://server/dir/file
```

%40 doesn't appear to work.

```
[~]# ftp domain.com
ftp: connect: Connection refused
ftp> quit
[~]# ftp some_user%40domain.com@domain.com
ftp: some_user%40domain.com@domain.com: Name or service not known
ftp> quit
```

All I've got is to open the ftp program and use the domain and enter the user when asked. Usually, a password is required anyway, so the interactive nature probably isn't problematic.

```
[~]# ftp domain.com
Connected to domain.com (173.254.13.235).
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 2 of 1000 allowed.
220-Local time is now 02:47. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Name (domain.com:user): some_user@domain.com
331 User some_user@domain.com OK. Password required
Password:
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
```

Answer (score 1):

curl -f -s --disable-epsv -u someone@somewhere.com:gr8p455w0rd -T /some/dir/filename ftp://somewher.com/ByramHealthcareCenters/byram06-2011.csv

Answer (score -3):

I've never seen the `-u` parameter. But if you want to use an "@", how about stating it as "\@"?

That way it should be interpreted as you intend. You know something like

```
ftp -u user\@domain.tld@ftp.host.tld
```

Comment: Can't use \@.  The shell will interpret the \@ as a plain @ and process it before the ftp command ever sees it.   You have to use %40 (hex/ascii for @) which the shell will ignore and the ftp command will interpret as @.

Comment: If you have never seen -u parameter (and obviously have never tested it) why you suggest to use it?