# php cURL password contains @

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to use cURL with the proxy setting, which was working fine before I changed my password to use the `@` sign.

This is how I define the proxy:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://test:test@test@10.20.5.15:90");
```

Is there any way to use a proxy pass with the `@` sign (in my case the password is `test@test`) and get cURL to work?

Comment: Might wanna take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648292/escaping-curl-symbol-with-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use linux command line ftp with a @ sign in my username?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/814322/how-to-use-linux-command-line-ftp-with-a-sign-in-my-username) - the same method can be used for the password parameter.

Comment: You should always attempt to find an existing post on the site before asking a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use %40 instead of "@" :

`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://test:test%40test@10.20.5.15:90");`
But it's better to use `CURLOPT_USERPWD` like @lix said ...

Comment: what if the password contains `:` ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using the [cURL set_opts](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) methods to set your username and password.

> **CURLOPT_USERPWD**
>    A username and password formatted as "[username]:[password]" to use
>   for the connection.

An example would look like this -

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "test:test@test");
```

Comment: what if the password contains `:` ?

Comment: @beppe9000 - you can try use the url encoded version of `:` which is `%3A`. I used this site to convert it https://www.urlencoder.org/.

Comment: Thats the same kinda solution from the other answer

Comment: well php has a builtin `urlencode` function, so I'd use that, like so: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, urlencode($user).':'.urlencode($password).'@'.$host.':'.$port);`