# How to pass a password to the vault-id in a bash script?

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I have a bash script that runs multiple ansible-playbooks.

eg.before encryption

```
ansible-playbook check_patch_applied.yml --extra-vars="target=123 patch_number=232323" -v t
ansible-playbook apply_patch.yml --extra-vars="target=np026 patch_number=232323" -v
```

I have recently encrypted the vault. Instead of keeping the vault password on a file on the server (which I think is insecure), I would prefer to type it in and then use that throughout the bash script to run the playbooks.

I don't want to have to type in the password for each playbook. I just want to type it in once at the beginning of the script and then pass it to the ansible-playbook lines

I tried this

```bash
read -p "Please enter the Ansible Vault password ? : " vault_password
vault_password=${vault_password,,}

ansible-playbook check_patch_applied.yml --extra-vars="target=123 patch_number=232323" --vault-id < (echo ${vault_password})' but I get syntax errors. Any ideas please ? Thanks in advance

I also tried this:
ansible-playbook check_patch_applied.yml --extra-vars="target=$target patch_number=$i" --vault-id @prompt < (echo "${vault_password}")

./patch.sh: line 117: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./patch.sh: line 117: `    ansible-playbook check_patch_applied.yml --extra-vars="target=$target patch_number=$i" -v --vault-id @prompt < (echo "${vault_password}")'
```

I don't want to use --vault-password-file and I do not want to keep the vault password on the server.

Comment: What syntax error are you getting? It looks like you have a mismatched single quote there, and note that `<(...)` has no space between `<` and `(`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution adapted from [an other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76236662/9401096). The trick is to use `/bin/cat` as the vault password file while providing the password from stdin:

```bash
read -p "Please enter the Ansible Vault password ? : " vault_password

echo ${vault_password} | ansible-playbook check_patch_applied.yml --extra-vars="target=123 patch_number=232323" --vault-password-file=/bin/cat
```

This will ask your password interactively while being able to reuse it in different ansible commands in the same script without storing it on disk.

Comment: I tried that, but I get ERROR! Decryption failed (no vault secrets were found that could decrypt) on .....

Comment: Password is correct

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I see what you mean. My ansible version is 2.9.27 and python is 2.7.5 , maybe that is an issue. We are doing everything else the same.

Comment: Note: I blindly used the parameter expansion from your question in my answer thinking it was a wanted "feature". I now get it was not expected (i.e. to transform script input to lowercase). Fixed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hello All and thanks for the help.
This works for me:

```
read -p "Please enter the Ansible Vault password ? : " vault_password

echo ${vault_password} | ansible-playbook check_patch_applied.yml --extra-vars="target=$target patch_number=$i" --vault-password-file=/bin/cat
```

Pretty much what Zeitounator had but just removed the ,,

Comment: Because [the parameter expansion `${variable,,}` would expand to the value of `$variable` with all character in lower case ...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500275/266568) resulting into a "changed" or different password ...

Comment: I used the lowcase parameter expansion in my answer because it was an implicit step in your example script in the question. So I inferred you wanted a lowercase password on all occasions. But it looks like you did not know what `${somevar,,}` was doing. I fixed my answer accordingly. Note that like everyone else on SO you could have fixed my answer directly rather than providing one that is now a duplicate.